# Simpledialog2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sdIntContent' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, simpledialog

I was working on jquery mobile and have used simpledialog2 for creating dialogs.

My code

```
<li><a href="#" data-rel="dialog" onclick="return openpopup();" style="font-weight:normal;">Register</a></li>



function openpopup() {
    $('#mobile-login-panel').simpledialog2({
       autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    height: 'auto',
    headerText: 'Sign in',
    headerClose: true,
    width:'auto',
    headerClose: true,
        blankContent:"SomeHtml"


    });
    $("div.ui-simpledialog-container ").appendTo($("form#frmdiaLogin"));
    return false;
    }
```

Now this dialog is opened correctly. But on closing is throwing error at

```
$.mobile.sdCurrentDialog.sdIntContent.find('select').each(function() {
```

Any solutions?

Comment: It happens the same to me. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. But i had to move to ahead

Comment: Did you change the library? If so... which library did you use?

Comment: Jquery mobile now have their own dialog http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0-beta.1/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html you can go through it

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could fix it was to use the uncompressed version of SimpleDialog2.js and change the following:

```
if ( self.options.mode === 'blank' ) {
        $.mobile.sdCurrentDialog.sdIntContent.find('select').each(function() {
            if ( $(this).data('nativeMenu') == false ) {
                $(this).data('selectmenu').menuPage.remove();
                $(this).data('selectmenu').screen.remove();
                $(this).data('selectmenu').listbox.remove();
            }
        });
    }
```

to

```
if ( self.options.mode === 'blank' ) {
        if ($.mobile.sdCurrentDialog) {
            $.mobile.sdCurrentDialog.sdIntContent.find('select').each(function() {
                if ( $(this).data('nativeMenu') == false ) {
                    if ( $(this).data('selectmenu') ) {
                        $(this).data('selectmenu').menuPage.remove();
                        $(this).data('selectmenu').screen.remove();
                        $(this).data('selectmenu').listbox.remove();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should start at line 337 of jquery.mobile.SimpleDialog2.js